# What is the time complexity performance of Scala's Vector data structure?

Tags: algorithm, scala, performance, data-structures

I know that most of the `Vector` methods are effectively O(1) (constant time) because of the tree they use, but I cannot find any information on the contains method. My first thought is that it would have to be O(n) to check all the elements but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering the question in the title, [performance characteristics](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html) ([2.13 docs version](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/performance-characteristics.html)) of basic operations `head`, `tail`, `apply`, `update`, `prepend`, `append`, `insert` are all listed as **eC** for `Vector`:

> **eC** The operation takes effectively constant time, but this might depend on some assumptions such as maximum length of a vector or distribution of hash keys.

You are correct `contains` is O(N), as there is no hashing or nothing else that would avoid the need to compare with all items. Still, if you want to be sure, it is best to check the implementation.

As finding the correct implementation in the library sources can be difficult because of many traits and overrides used to implement the containers, the best way to check this is the debugger. Use a code like:

```
val v = Vector(0, 1, 2)
v.contains(1)
```

Use the debugger to step into `v.contains` and the source you will see is:

```
  def contains[A1 >: A](elem: A1): Boolean = exists (_ == elem)
```

If you are still not convinced at this point, some more "step into" will lead you to:

```
  def exists(p: A => Boolean): Boolean = {
    var res = false
    while (!res && hasNext) res = p(next())
    res
  }
```